# Match() Against() using joined columns

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have 3 tables, t1, t2, and t3 as follows:

```
t1
___
t1id
name
address
type

t2
___
t2id
title

t3
____
t3id
t1id
t2id
```

I have a full-text index on t1 covering `name`, `address`, and `type`.

What do I have to do to make the following query work? Just adding a full-text index to `t2.title` won't work, will it?

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name,MATCH(t1.name,t1.address,t1.type,t2.title) AGAINST ('query') as rank 
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t1.t1id = t3.t1id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t3.t2id = t2.t2id
WHERE MATCH(t1.name,t1.address,t1.type,t2.title) AGAINST('query' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION) 
HAVING rank > 0.2 
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0a59/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Full-Text Restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-restrictions.html):

> The [`MATCH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) column list must match exactly the column list in some `FULLTEXT` index definition for the table, unless this [`MATCH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) is `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. Boolean-mode searches can be done on nonindexed columns, although they are likely to be slow.

You can instead combine multiple `MATCH()` expressions:

```
SELECT   t1.id, t1.name,
         MATCH(t1.name, t1.address, t1.type) AGAINST ('query')
       + MATCH(t2.title                    ) AGAINST ('query')
      AS rank
FROM     t1 LEFT JOIN t3 USING (t1id)
            LEFT JOIN t2 USING (t2id)
WHERE    MATCH(t1.name, t1.address, t1.type) AGAINST ('query')
       + MATCH(t2.title                    ) AGAINST ('query')
       > 0.2
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Comment: When adding multiple `match()` expressions, the 'rank' of anything matching `t2.title` is 0. Therefore anything matching on `t2.title` does not rank by relevance?

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios: You have a `FULLTEXT` index on that column?

Comment: Yea. I have one that covers all three of the t1 columns, and one that covers that single t2 column. and I did it in BOOLEAN mode

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios: I notice you've accepted this answer - did you manage to solve the problem with `t2.title`?  It had me stumped!

Comment: I have not been able to fix it, however I accepted the answer because you're the only one helping me with it. haha. Are you able to recreate what I am seeing?

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios: Perhaps upload some test data onto [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and provide a link here if you can reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: Here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0a59/7. As you can see, two of the records should rank on 'fun' since they both have that tag, but all three rank 0

Comment: As documented under [Natural Language Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-natural-language.html): "*Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is four characters.*"

Comment: okay, what about this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0a59/17 It should rank the store tagged 'sushi' the highest (which it does) but it doesn't rank the other row with type  'store'?

Comment: The order of the columns in the `FULLTEXT` index that you've created in the sqlfiddle are not the same as you gave in your question above: they must be in exactly the same order within the `MATCH` clause.